# chunksize vs line boundary

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2

This is the code from https://fs2.io/#/getstarted/example.

```
import cats.effect.{IO, IOApp}
import fs2.{Stream, text}
import fs2.io.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths

object Converter extends IOApp.Simple {

  val converter: Stream[IO, Unit] = {
    def fahrenheitToCelsius(f: Double): Double =
      (f - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0)

    Files[IO].readAll(Paths.get("testdata/fahrenheit.txt"), 4096)
      .through(text.utf8Decode)
      .through(text.lines)
      .filter(s => !s.trim.isEmpty && !s.startsWith("//"))
      .map(line => fahrenheitToCelsius(line.toDouble).toString)
      .intersperse("\n")
      .through(text.utf8Encode)
      .through(Files[IO].writeAll(Paths.get("testdata/celsius.txt")))
  }

  def run: IO[Unit] =
    converter.compile.drain
}
```

In the `Files[IO].readAll(Paths.get("testdata/fahrenheit.txt"), 4096)`, In my understanding, readAll, read 4096 bytes a time. and `.through(text.lines)` split at line boundary.
My question is: if the 4096th byte is in the middle of line, why not the number in that line split into two part.

Comment: _My question is: if the 4096th byte is in the middle of line, why not the number in that line split into two part."_ - `text.lines` is a pipe, if the current chunk doesn't end in a line boundary, it reads the next chunk before emitting the next element.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks. I was confused with `lines` at other programming languages.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, it does what any method called lines would do. Return each line.

Comment: The chunking aspect of `readAll` is practically an implementation detail. It doesn't semantically affect the result value at all and is used only for maximizing efficiency.